# How to disable my button based on dynamically generated radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

As you can see my radio button ids are dynamic.
I want to disable input type file button  if my value value="0" or value="2" radio buttons without affecting other section.

```html
/*First Section*/
<input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" id="Button_select_1" />
<div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Kindly submit your response" id="10_3" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="1" />
            <label>Yes</label>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input checked="checked" id="10_4" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="0" />
            <label>No</label>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input id="10_5" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="2" />
            <label>N/A</label>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
/*Second Section*/
<input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" id="Button_select_1" />
<div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Kindly submit your response" id="11_3" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="1" />
            <label>Yes</label>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input checked="checked" id="11_4" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="0" />
            <label>No</label>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input id="11_5" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="2" />
            <label>N/A</label>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
 /*Third Section*/
 <input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" id="Button_select_1" />
<div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Kindly submit your response" id="16_3" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="1" />
            <label>Yes</label>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input checked="checked" id="16_4" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="0" />
            <label>No</label>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input id="16_5" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="2" />
            <label>N/A</label>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
....
/*nth Section*/
<input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" id="Button_select_1" />
<div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Kindly submit your response" id="nth_3" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="1" />
            <label>Yes</label>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input checked="checked" id="nth_4" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="0" />
            <label>No</label>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input id="nth_5" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="2" />
            <label>N/A</label>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm loading my form dynamically  so my radio button ids are dynamic well. Each section contain input type file button. My input type file id will have the same id that is "Button_select_1" for some reason.

Comment: `id` attribute **must** have unique value, if you need to identify `<input type="file">`, then use `class` attribute instead.

Comment: Also don't nest your labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there can be more than 1 checkbox/radio button checked at a time throughout the entire collection of elements you need some means by which to distinguish them as a group, otherwise as they are all called the same thing you will only be able to check one at a time. To that end you can remove ID attributes generally as they often cause issues and use a `name[x]` type syntax for the radio button names. If there are a unlimited possible number of these, dynamically generated, it becomes easy to assign a number ( or unique string ) within the square braces in whatever code generates the sections.

As mentioned by @mplungian, nesting the elements within a common parent ( a `section` is perfect ) it becomes very easy to process the checking of radio buttons and the required enable/disable of the file input. A `delegated` event listener, bound to the page in this case, will work regardless of the number of dynamic elements added to the DOM and some very simple code within the event handler will find the `file input` and disable it if any radio other than the `Yes` radio is checked. As that is to be the default behaviour and the `No` is selected by default it makes sense to disable the file input initially.

The `name[x]` type syntax can also help when processing a large dataset serverside as that `x` value acts as a key within the array!

```js
document.addEventListener('change',e=>{
  if( e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement && e.target.type=='radio' ){
    let bttn=e.target.closest('section').querySelector('[type="file"]');
        bttn.disabled=( parseInt( e.target.value )!==1 );
    }
})
```

```css
body{
  counter-reset:sections;
}

section:before{
  counter-increment:sections;
  content:'Section: 'counter(sections)
}
```

```html
<section>
  <input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" disabled />
  <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <label><input data-val="true" data-val-required="Kindly submit your response"  name="AnswerResponse[1]" type="radio" value="1" />Yes</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <label><input checked="checked" name="AnswerResponse[1]" type="radio" value="0" />No</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <label><input name="AnswerResponse[1]" type="radio" value="2" /> N/A</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



<section>
  <input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" disabled />
  <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <label><input data-val="true" data-val-required="Kindly submit your response"  name="AnswerResponse[2]" type="radio" value="1" />Yes</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <label><input checked="checked" name="AnswerResponse[2]" type="radio" value="0" />No</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <label><input name="AnswerResponse[2]" type="radio" value="2" />N/A</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



<section>
  <input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" disabled />
  <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <label><input data-val="true" data-val-required="Kindly submit your response" name="AnswerResponse[3]" type="radio" value="1" />Yes</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <label><input checked="checked" name="AnswerResponse[3]" type="radio" value="0" />No</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <label><input name="AnswerResponse[3]" type="radio" value="2" />N/A</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



<section>
  <input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" disabled />
  <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <label><input data-val="true" data-val-required="Kindly submit your response" name="AnswerResponse[n]" type="radio" value="1" />Yes</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <label><input checked="checked" name="AnswerResponse[n]" type="radio" value="0" />No</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <label><input name="AnswerResponse[n]" type="radio" value="2" />N/A</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion

1. Find the closest static container of all the sections and delegate from there - I made a div with id="container"
2. wrap each section in a div with class section to be able to navigate to the input from the related radio
3. Initialise if needed  - if the radios may already have been selected from the server

With this code the IDs of the radios and file elements are not needed.

I also removed the nested label which is not valid HTML but this change is not relevant to the question

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches("[name=AnswerResponse]")) return; // not a radio
  tgt.closest(".section").querySelector("[type=file]").disabled = ["0", "2"].includes(tgt.value)
});
// init: 
document.querySelectorAll(".section").forEach(section => {
  const selectedRad = section.querySelector("input[name=AnswerResponse]:checked");
  if (selectedRad) {
    section.querySelector("[type=file]").disabled = ["0", "2"].includes(selectedRad.value);
  }  
})
```

```css
.section {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="section">
    /*First Section*/
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" id="Button_select_1" />
    <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Kindly submit your response" id="10_3" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="1" />
            Yes</label>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input checked="checked" id="10_4" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="0" />
 No</label>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input id="10_5" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="2" />
N/A</label>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    /*Second Section*/
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" id="Button_select_1" />
    <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Kindly submit your response" id="11_3" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="1" />
Yes</label>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input checked="checked" id="11_4" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="0" />
No</label>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input id="11_5" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="2" />
N/A</label>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    /*Third Section*/
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" id="Button_select_1" />
    <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Kindly submit your response" id="16_3" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="1" />
Yes</label>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input checked="checked" id="16_4" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="0" />
No</label>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input id="16_5" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="2" />
N/A</label>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    .... /*nth Section*/
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" id="Button_select_1" />
    <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Kindly submit your response" id="nth_3" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="1" />
Yes</label>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input checked="checked" id="nth_4" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="0" />
No</label>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input id="nth_5" name="AnswerResponse" type="radio" value="2" />
N/A</label>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```